# Is it overdoing it to put all client side files behind an authorization check?

Tags: reactjs, web, authorization

Is it ok that static content that normally would load only on an authorized user's page be publicly requestable?

Let's say there are two routes `/public-route` and `/private-route`

`public-route` loads:

```
/public-route.html
/public-route.js
/logo.jpg
```

`private-route` loads:

```
/private-route.html
/private-route.js
/logo.jpg
```

To load the `/private-route` page the user needs to be authenticated. Requesting `/private-route.html` as a unauthenticated user will return a `401`. But what about if the user directly requested `/private-route.js`? Is it too much to put all client side files behind an authorization check?

I'm also looking at this from the standpoint of React components. Say, a given page has certain components only available to certain types of users (guest, user, admin). Should I create 3 separate App.js'?

Comment: Found an opinion about the matter: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115880/can-i-safely-store-my-admin-scripts-in-a-publicly-available-script-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what kind of app you are dealing with, if the app is considered sensitive it is not acceptable to allow an unauthenticated user to access any of the content that is supposed to be delivered to authenticated users only. If you are working on a professional app and are concerned about security you need to address this.

You may want to place public and private content in two different sub directories of your app which are served by different routes: for example `your.site.com/public` will return files and resources from `/public`, whereas `your.site.com/private` will first perform a check to see if the request is authenticated and if so return files and resources from `/private`. Doing so would prevent an attacker to download your `private` website code and resources. If anybody can create a fake/trial account and authenticate to the private section, this of course becomes irrelevant.

One thing that you may want to make sure is performing a check at the api level to verify that private endpoints are being invoked by an authenticated user, the most important part to protect in a web application is the data not the frontend source code.

The way you handle this is highly dependent on the tech you are using on your backend. With node and express for example you would typically add a custom middleware to each of the private endpoints. Some higher level frameworks can also handle that for you.